# Setting up AngularJS for TypeScript in Sublime Text 3

Tags: angularjs, typescript, sublimetext3

Good day, I am trying to use AngularJS in TypeScript, problem is, i have just shifted to Sublime Text 3 from VS2013, for some OS reason, I have dug around google for answers, but i haven't found one. so I'd like to know how i could setup AngularJS for TypeScript in Sublime (note: TypeScript is already configured in Sublime; I'm looking specifically for how to set up AngularJS for TypeScript). thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if I got your question, but pretty much, after installing the [plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Sublime-Plugin) you need to install AngularJs TypeScript Definitions and reference them in your code.

For definition management I use [tsd](http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/). It's pretty much like bower (oh God... one more dependency manager...). You can install it using `npm install tsd -g`, then, in your project folder initialize `tsd` repo

```
tsd init
```

And install AngularJs Definitions

```
tsd query angular --action install --save
```

And finally reference them in your source code by adding the reference directive (tsd will install each definition separately, and `tsd.d.ts` consolidates all installed dependencies, so you don't need to bloat your files with references):

```typescript
/// <reference path="typings/tsd.d.ts" />
```

And that's it. You should be able to get code hint now:

[image: AngularJs typescript code hint]

Now, did you do all this and still don't get it working?

Comment: Yes thanks, it's just that my common sense went on vacation that day.

Comment: It looks like people is still working on a tsd for Angular 2 https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/2333. But you could also try `tsd query angular2 --action install --save`